# Using Windows VM as a print server for Linux clients?

Tags: networking, windows, printing

All Linux household with a nice-ish GDI laser printer (FujiXerox Docuprint p115w wifi) gifted to me. No Linux drivers are available.

How could I install a Windows VM and expose that to the network as a print server that works with Linux clients?

Comment: What's the exact model of this printer?

Comment: Edited to add exact model

Comment: Are you sure it's not a DocuPrint M115 w?

Comment: Indeed. Autocorrect on the phone got me. Apologies

Comment: Well the website doesn't have any Linux driver, but have you actually tried using it? Maybe Ubuntu has something generic that'll at least let you use it as a printer, if nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I Worked on it for two straight weekends, including similar models, generic GDI drivers, etc. Nothing. I haven't had this problem in a decade because I just stick to supported hardware ... But it's a gift.

Comment: It turns out there's more than one 115 model. I'm finding M115, P115, CM115 and some others. I'm not sure if there's a significant difference, but could you confirm which?

Comment: Hmm. So not even generic drivers worked? I'll see if I can find anything.

Comment: Don't waste your time on the driver. Fuji's official statement is that this is a GDI printer and will never have any kind of Linux support.

Comment: This is something: http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=105500&sid=7ea283227468182fc2ab4e3fb1f348b7

Comment: You could also try some of these http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Generic/Generic-GDI_Printer

Comment: Thanks. I previously tried both of those. No luck yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Methods I can think of:

- Windows (server 2008 R2 or newer) VM + IIS to enable internet printing (IPP). This should allow you to print using the drivers stored on the server as IPP sends the job over as an encapsulated PDF file. [TechNet article for this feature.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126092(v=ws.10).aspx) I've never tried this method but it seems like it should work.
- Windows (any) VM + "web print" server from printer management software inside  windows. We use [PaperCut](https://www.papercut.com/) for this purpose at my work. It's free for up to 5 users and will print PDF files with the web print feature with minimal configuration. This will require saving as PDF and using a web based service on the print server to send the document over to the printer. The server will use it's drivers to do the actual rendering of the print job.
- Windows (any) VM + Google Cloud Print + Google Chrome. Similar to the above but uses Google's servers to do the web portion. Requires the VM to be logged in and running Chrome's background services app at all times.
- Unless you have several spare toner refills buy a new printer that has good compatibility. Honestly, the level of effort and frustration you will likely go through to get a working solution is not worth it for these consumer printers.

Comment: I was told that the iis method isn't dependable because the implementation and port are off, which I immediately believed since it was a Microsoft product under Ballers, but i hasn't considered using Cloud Print. I will probably use this toner out then get an HP or something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've never tried it so I can't say for sure one way or the other. I do recall there was a different implementation in server 2003 and XP but I'm not sure of the details on any of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Virtualbox, from the Oracle site preferably.
2. Install the corresponding extension pack to get guest support for USB2 and USB3.
3. Forward the USB port the printer is connected to, to the Windows vm using Virtualbox settings.
4. From Virtuabox settings, change the guest's network setting to bridged so that you can connect to the guest easily from all other computers.
5. Share you printer using Windows printer settings so that it's visible by all other computers.

These are the main steps you need to take and you will find hundreds of posts for each one of them.

Comment: First of all -- Thank you. But ... at that end point, Windows is going to expect the client computer to have drivers for the printer in order to print, correct? No computers in the house will have that driver because it's not available for Linux. (p.s. I edited my question to make this part clearer)

Comment: Why do you want to expose it as a print server then?  How have you designed it?

Comment: None of the computers in the house have windows installed, so the printer is currently unusable. I need to install the driver a Windows installation (which will have to be a VM) and have some way for the multiple Linux computers to print to it.

Comment: Right now, the workaround is to use Dropbox to store a PDF and the Android printer app to print via wifi

Comment: Yes, I saw the edited version.  I hadn't realized all the other systems use Linux.  Let's see if someone else can help you better.  You are right.  If there are no drivers for the Linux server, there won't be for all others too.

Comment: I positively hate this about Windows' printer driver model. If the print server has the driver, why the f do the clients need it, too? Grr.

Comment: @BoDangRen because there's no translation driver for it, to let Linux talk to Windows to talk to the printer.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of at this moment is that you could share a folder on the print server vm and send all the files that need to be printed to that folder and print them from the vm itself using a corresponding app or something.  I don't know.  :-D

Comment: @stormlord I was considering exactly that

Comment: I'm also considering osx in the VM shared via cups.